# Can't update SQL Bit column with ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I have an ASP .NET Core web app, and when I created the project the authentication was set up automatically using the individual user accounts option. The database tables for user accounts/roles were also created automatically.

I created my own ApplicationUser class which inherits from IdentityUser, and I added parameters for FirstName, LastName and LockoutReason. (I added these fields to the DB table as well) Now I'm trying to add a feature to allow someone to manually lock out a user, and I can't seem to update the LockoutEnabled field in the database. Every time I do, it automatically gets reset to false.

Here is a picture of the form:
[image]

And the GET/POST code for it:

```
//GET Users lock
    public async Task<IActionResult> Lock(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var userFromDb = await _db.ApplicationUser.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (userFromDb == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            return View(userFromDb);
        }
    }

    //POST Users lock
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Lock(string Id, ApplicationUser model)
    {
        var userFromDb = await _db.Users.Where(u => u.Id == Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        userFromDb.LockoutEnd = model.LockoutEnd;
        userFromDb.LockoutEnabled = true;
        userFromDb.AccessFailedCount = model.AccessFailedCount;
        userFromDb.LockoutReason = model.LockoutReason;

        _db.ApplicationUser.Update(userFromDb);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));           
    }
```

ApplicationUser.cs

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{        
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string LockoutReason { get; set; }
}
```

When I click the Lock button, the LockoutEnd and LockoutReason fields are updated correctly, but the LockoutEnabled field remains false and the account isn't locked out.

New POST method after trying to implement solution:

```
//POST Users lock
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Lock(string Id, ApplicationUser model)
    {
        var userFromDb = await _db.Users.Where(u => u.Id == Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        userFromDb.LockoutEnd = model.LockoutEnd;            
        userFromDb.AccessFailedCount = model.AccessFailedCount;
        userFromDb.LockoutReason = model.LockoutReason;

        _db.ApplicationUser.Update(userFromDb);            
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

        var user2 = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userFromDb.Id);
        var result = await _userManager.SetLockoutEnabledAsync(user2, true);

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));           
    }
```

Comment: Try updating then saving, reference (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799329/updating-sql-bit-column-from-entity-framework)

Comment: I just gave that a shot and it didn't work for me                                                                  Edit: Thanks for the help though

Comment: Not sure why then, maybe someone else can help.

Comment: have you looked at the queries app sends to db? is field included in select and update statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the combination of the two proprieties The `LockoutEnabled` and `LockoutEnd`.

The `LockoutEnabled` is an indicator to see if the user could be locked out or not, and the `LockoutEnd` is a DateTimeOffset. So in order to lock the user set the lockout to true and put the value of `LockoutEnd` in the future, because A value in the past means the user is not locked out.

Comment: Oh wow I totally misunderstood how the lockouts work. For some reason I was thinking that LockoutEnabled was an indicator to see if the user is currently locked out, and would be set to 1 until the LockoutEnd date passed. I just updated the LockoutEnabled values manually, and now my lockout feature works as intended. Thanks!

Comment: You can also make your own locking/disabling mechanism, by adding a propriety to the User e.g.: `IsDisabled`, then create your own `SignInManager` which inherits from SignInManager and within it you can override the `PasswordSignInAsync` to check if the user is disabled or not.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot achieve this by altering `LockoutEnabled` property.

Instead, you need to add custom property such as `IsEnabled`

- On Register Action Modify Application user

  `var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, IsEnabled = true };`
- On PasswordSigninAsync  add IsEnabled check

'

```
if (user.IsEnabled)
     return base.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, rememberMe, shouldLockout);

return Task.FromResult<SignInStatus>(SignInStatus.LockedOut);
```

Comment: That was suggested in a comment, it didn't work for me. The bit field (LockoutEnabled) is the only field that won't update.

Comment: Thanks for the help - it turns out I was just misunderstanding how the lockout works but I may end up taking your advice and create my own SignInManager and customized lockout functionality.

Comment: You have checked @Hameed's post as answer. Did It work?

Answer (score 2):

`UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager`

`_userManager = userManager; //DI'd via CTOR for the class`

it is never done with direct access with the table from the user table.

in your case you might need to grab the user with a call to
`var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.Id)`

because you might not have enough information with the pass through from the post populated within the model variable.

```
//used from with in method
//model.LockoutEnabled will be either true or false depending on your selection
//from the view.
var result = await _userManager.SetLockoutEnabledAsync(user, model.LockoutEnabled);
```

this returns `IdentityResult` which has Errors collection Or bool Succeeded properties, can be handled as you like.

Comment: Does setting result to that value lock the user out or do I need to do something with that variable? I tried just calling await _userManager.SetLockoutEnabledAsync(user, true) and it didn't work. I also set user equal to await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userFromDb.Id)

Comment: So it turns out I didn't even need to be updating LockoutEnabled, I just misunderstood how account lockouts work. I appreciate the help though!

Comment: do you have the items in Startup.cs set for Identity? `services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(config => {});`